# How to override stripe module?

Tags: checkout, layout, overrides, customization

I'm trying to override this template:

`vendor/stripe/module-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html`

with

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/payment/form.html`

But it doesn't work. What might be a problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a few hours I realized that editing it in Magento_Checkout wasn't correct. The correct path was:

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/StripeIntegration_Payments/web/template/payment/form.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this way :-

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/themename/YourModule_Name/web/template/payment/form.html
```

After this run command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: No thats my exact path, sorry I mistyped it the first time, I just edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Override file on below path

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/YourModule_Name/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html

And run below command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Hope this help you.

Comment: This is incorrect path

Comment: I wrote your moduname. It means stripe module not checkout. I Wasn't said checkout module.but happy to hear you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

For future people looking for an answer, first check how it's registered in the original module file '**registration.php**'
and then you can save it correctly inside your theme with that name.

> vendor/stripe/module-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/StripeIntegration_Payments/web/template/payment/form.html

and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`